# Bowing at the royal coat of arms

Tags: halacha, avodah-zarah, malchut-royalty, derech-eretz-manners, civil-procedure

In British Magistrate and Crown Courts the royal coat of arms is located behind the bench where the magistrates or judge sit. It is etiquette for solicitors/barristers and anyone giving evidence to bow briefly in the direction of the coat of arms out of respect.

Is one allowed to do so according to halacha?[image]

Comment: Yes.  It is not an idol.  See https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/100755/did-mordechai-bow-to-achashverosh/100762#100762